# Parsing Json in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have following code where I am having syntax error issue when appending array children to json object. Any documentation and online help I have searched (and I have searched extensively) only gives examples with static values. I need to append arrays using plsql cursor values as shown below.

Please advise what is the correct way of appending cursor values to json arrays.

Below is my code.

```
FOR i IN getHdrRec LOOP
        -- Create JSON payload
        l_json.put('BillToCustomerNumber',i.bill_to_account_id);
        l_json.put('BillToCustomerName',i.bill_to_account_name);
        l_json.put('BillToSite',i.bill_to_party_site_number);
        l_json.put('DueDate',i.due_date);
        l_json.put('BusinessUnit',i.company_id);
        l_json.put('CrossReference',i.document_id);
        l_json.put('TransactionDate',i.trx_date);
        l_json.put('CreationDate',i.creation_date);
        l_json.put('ShipToCustomerNumber',i.ship_to_account_id);
        l_json.put('ShipToSite',i.ship_to_party_site_number);
        l_json.put('TransactionSource','Equipment Rental');
        l_json.put('TransactionType','Invoice');
        l_json.put('InvoiceCurrencyCode','USD');


          FOR j IN getlnrec (i.document_id) LOOP

/* this way is not working */
              l_children.append(json_object_t(key 'LineNumber' value j.line_id));

/* and this way is also not working */          l_children.append(json_object_t('{"ItemNumber":||"||j.item_code||"}'));
              l_children.append(json_object_t('{"Description":||"||j.item_description||"}'));
              l_children.append(json_object_t('{"Quantity":||"||j.Quantity||"}'));
              l_children.append(json_object_t('{"UnitSellingPrice":||"||j.line_value||"}'));
*
  END LOOP;


      l_json.put('receivablesInvoiceLines',l_children);
    END LOOP;


    envelope := l_json.to_clob;
```

in the above code, the l_children.append section is causing the error.

here is the error

```
Error report -
ORA-40441: JSON syntax error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.JDOM_T", line 4
ORA-06512: at "SYS.JSON_OBJECT_T", line 28
ORA-06512: at "INT_STG_DATA.XXRR_BILLING_INVOICE_PROC", line 113
ORA-06512: at "INT_STG_DATA.XXRR_BILLING_INVOICE_PROC", line 113
ORA-06512: at line 4
40441. 00000 -  "JSON syntax error"
*Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) data had invalid
           syntax and could not be parsed.
*Action:   Provide JSON data with the correct syntax.
```

This sounds simple enough, any help will be appreciated.

Darsh

Comment: Please post reproducible example. There's no any information of what `l_children` is and what is your source data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the input that you are passing to the [`json_object_t`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-10062646-E36F-48B1-9F24-751B613DFB5A) constructor; it is not a valid JSON string. You need to insert some single quotes into the expression to make it valid.

```
'{"Description":||"||j.item_description||"}'
```

should become:

```
'{"Description":"' || j.item_description || '"}'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of construction of JSON object by concatenation instead of key/value constructor?

Comment: @astentx the `key/value` constructor applies to [`json_object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370), not `json_object_t`

Comment: Okay, it may be achieved by composition of `json_object_t` constructor and `json_object` function (or via no-args constructor and `put` method). That is much safer than concatenation.

Comment: @astentx if you feel that is the right thing to do then just post it as an answer